# webpack code splitting - creates an extra bunlde: 0.bundle.js

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I have the following webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        source1: './frontend/source1.js',
        source2: './frontend/source2.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/bundles')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['static/bundles'])
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader', //  для .vue-файлов
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                    }
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
};
```

and when I run webpack I expect it to produce two files: `source1.bundle.js` and `source2.bundle.js`.

But it also produces a mysterious `0.bundle.js` and puts it in the same directory as the other files.

[image]

Then when I open the browser I get an error:

[image]

because my bundles are being loaded from a separate absolute `/static/bundles/` directory, and this `0.bundle.js` is trying to get loaded from the current page instead of `/static/bundles/`. What is this file, and how do I specify a load path for it?

Comment: have you got a solution for this? i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to add a publicPath to the webpack config. Just wherever you're actually reading them from.

`output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/'
},`